# Best way to back up locally stored Certificates

Tags: certificates, windows, certificate-authority

What is the best way to back-up all the locally stored certificates on Windows 7?

An adware Trojan has installed fraudulent certificates as part of its payload.

Before I alter anything, I want to be able to easily back up to the initial state. Every certificate on the system needs to be copied: personal certificates, user account certificates and computer account certificates, certificates from all the installed browsers and everything else (even on the file system). I think that I might miss some if I just copy from the registry. I'm told that the Trojan was removed by an anti-virus some years ago so reproducing the reinfection isn't an option.